# How to put variable in bash script with ansible playbook

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, ansible

I need a put variable in script with an Ansible playbook. I get the variable from Jenkins 'build with parameter' but I can't put a " tag " variable in my script. How can I do that?

This is my script:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/asd/products/app/java8

tag=$(tag)

hzpid=$(ps aux  |grep /home/asd/products/app/hzcluster/ |grep -v grep |  awk '{print $2}' | sed -r 's/%/ /g')

echo $hzpid

if [[ -z $hzpid ]]; then

echo "no running applications"

else

kill -9 $hzpid &&  echo "running process terminated."

fi


nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dspring.profiles.active=dxl-dev -jar /home/asd/products/app/hzcluster/new/hzcluster-$tag-SNAPSHOT.jar > $LOG_DIR/hzcluster.log &

exit 0
```

This is my ansible-playbook:

```
- hosts: '{{ hosts }}'
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Run new hzcluster.jar
      shell: sh  '{{ sh_file }}'start-hzcluster2.sh '{{ tag }}'
```

Comment: What is the error that you get for this playbook

Comment: Doesn't make a error. Just script is not working cause don't take a tag parameter.

Comment: Is the script working manualy?

Comment: In the script you can give tag= $1 and then pass it from ansible

Comment: I don't know how i can

Comment: added below, please try

Answer (score 0):

In your shell script change from `tag=$(tag)` to `tag=$1`

Playbook:

```
- hosts: '{{ hosts }}'
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Run new hzcluster.jar
      shell: sh  '{{ sh_file }}'start-hzcluster2.sh '{{ tag }}'
```

Comment: Get error.
"Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/asd/products/app/hzcluster/new/hzcluster-1.4.563-SNAPSHOT.JAR", "stderr_lines": ["Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/asd/products/app/hzcluster/new/hzcluster-1.4.563-SNAPSHOT.JAR"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Comment: Now is it taking the tag parameter? I think yes, so the issue is now with shell script. ansible side its fine.